# Changing a Builder method

Tags: python, kivy

How to change a `Builder` class method behavior?
Let's say, I would like to change `load_string` method a little, for example, just so that when calling this method, 'Hi' printed.

I found this method in `BuilderBase` class (the link is below). Can I subclass `BuilderBase` or `Builder`?
I tried to subclass `Builder` this way:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
Label
    text: 'test'
"""

class New_builder(Builder):
  def load_string(self, *l, **kw):
    super().load_string(*l, **kw)
    print('hi')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return New_builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

And I get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
     class New_builder(Builder):
 TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/lang/builder.py

Comment: If may solution was helpful please mark it as correct and/or upvote it to signal that question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to change the original functionality totally but build upon it AKA decorate it. You could use a mix of decorator pattern and monkey patching as so:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """
Label
    text: 'test'
"""


# Create a decorator function that will add new functionality
def new_func(func):

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # your custome code can go before or after the call to the original function
        print("Hi")
        return result
    return inner

#Using monkeypatching monkey patch the Builder object to use the newly decorated function
Builder.load_string = new_func(Builder.load_string)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

This is because as was noted to me `Builder` is not a class but rather an object of class  `BaseBuilder` so it is impossible to inherit from it that is why we are swapping the old function for our newly created one. Also note that if `Builder` object method `load_string` is used inside the import library, by that I mean during import some code is executed that uses `load_string` this solution will not affect that code as the patching is done after import.

That being said the example was checked and it is working.

Comment: Yes, it works in that case, but in most cases I need to add my code in the middle of the original code (not at the beginning and not at the end). How can I do that?

Comment: @me2beats First off from what you are saying this resolves the question in the topic so please mark it as correct. If you would like to change the functionality inside that method create a new question and state in details what changes you would like to introduce. It is hard to answer such a broad question. Basically the idea is the same find method invocation in the `load_string` method and decorate those. If this is also not possible then you need to copy the code of the entire method introduce your changes and than monkey patch the `Builder` object with the new method.

Comment: @me2beats Note that your example uses inheritance to change functionality and from what you are saying you would like to totally modify it, so the question does not really reflect your needs.